# Factory has two methods, one is $http method with $promise - how to reference the other method from within the first one's success function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angular-services

In one of my factories I need to set a variable when data is fetched (through `$http`) so I can access it in my controller (the intention is to display a spinner image until the data is loaded).

```
.factory('LoadData', function LoadData($http, $q){
    return {

        getMyData: function(){
            return $http(
                // implementation of the call
            ).then(
                function(response){
                    var myData = response.data;

                    // this should be reference to the other method (getLoadStatus) 
                    // where I want to change its value to "true"

                    // this doesn't work - "this" or "self" don't work either because we're in another function
                    LoadData.getLoadStatus.status = true;
                }
            );
        },
        // by calling the below method from my controller,
        // I want to mark the completion of data fetching
        getLoadStatus = function(){

            var status = null;

            return status;

        }
    }
}
```

I hope you got the idea - how could this be accomplished? Also, I'm open to any suggestions which are aimed towards a better approach (I want to pick up best practice whenever possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually decide to use a promise in my controller after calling this service and when data is returned, I am simply making the status true. It seems that is best practice to have a promise returned when calling a service so I should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply store variable flag in closure:

```
.factory('LoadData', function LoadData($http, $q) {
    var status = false;
    return {
        getMyData: function() {
            status = false;
            return $http(/* implementation of the call */).then(function(response) {
                status = true;
                return response.data;
            });
        },
        getLoadStatus: function() {
            return status;
        }
    }
});
```

Also if `getMyData` loads fresh data every time, it's important to reset status to false before each request.

Answer (score 1):

Status is essentially a private variable; use it as:

```
.factory('LoadData', function LoadData($http, $q){
    var status = null; // ESSENTIALLY PRIVATE TO THE SERVICE
    return {
        getMyData: function(){
            return $http(...).then(function(response){
                ...
                status = true;
            });
        },
        getLoadStatus = function(){
            return status;
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: So, am I supposed to call it from my ctrl like so `$scope.foo = LoadData.displayNamesLoaded()`? It this case it returns `null` as that's the initial value and it's never updated because the `promise` is in the factory itself, not in the controller (the method i'm calling from there doesn't have a promise in the first place!)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

Here's one which I prefer to use:

```
.factory('LoadData', function LoadData($http, $q){
    var status = false;
    var service = {
        getMyData: getMyData,
        status: status
    };
    return service;

    function getMyData() {
        return $http(
            // implementation of the call
        ).then(
            function(response){
                var myData = response.data;
                status = true;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This provides good encapsulation of your methods and gives you a clean interface to export. No need for the getter method if you don't want it.

Inspiration via John Papa's Angular style guide (found [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#factories)).

Comment: OK, but could you let me know of a way I could get this status from my ctrl (so I can attach it to a $scope variable) in such a way it will update when data is successfully loaded (obviously change from `false` to `true` of status variable should change on my scope object. That's what causes problems for me.